# SQL query to get the latest entry of a record

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following sample data
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKydQ.png)
I want to get the latest mark for each student. Take Note that the column named Exam marks whether the work was an Exam or Not.

I want to get the latest record for each person where Exam = Yes

I tried the following

```
WITH ranked_messages AS (
select Student_number,Exam,Mark,Date_of_exam,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_number ORDER BY Date_of_exam DESC) as rnt
FROM new_table 
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_messages WHERE rnt = 1  and Exam = 'Yes'
```

and i got
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix4a4.png)

I'm expecting to get the following
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkjhP.png)

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Comment: Move `and Exam = 'Yes'` inside of your CTE, and everything will work as you want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample set, the latest record for D201 doesn't have Exam = 'Yes' so it will not get rnt = 1 from the inner query. So, you probably just need to move the Exam-qualifier into the inner query. Like this:

```
WITH ranked_messages AS (
    SELECT Student_number,Exam,Mark,Date_of_exam,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Student_number ORDER BY Date_of_exam DESC) as rnt
    FROM new_table 
    WHERE Exam = 'Yes'
)
SELECT * FROM ranked_messages WHERE rnt = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b63280/3

Here is the example data and schema.

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
  Student_number INT,
  Exam VARCHAR(3),
  Mark INT,
  Date_of_exam DATE
);

INSERT INTO new_table VALUES
  (1, 'Yes', 80, '2022-01-01'),
  (1, 'No', 70, '2022-02-01'),
  (2, 'Yes', 90, '2022-01-01'),
  (2, 'Yes', 85, '2022-02-01'),
  (3, 'No', 60, '2022-01-01'),
  (3, 'No', 55, '2022-02-01'),
  (3, 'Yes', 75, '2022-03-01'),
  (4, 'Yes', 95, '2022-02-01'),
  (4, 'No', 80, '2022-03-01');
```

Then you can query like this:

```
SELECT Student_number, Date_of_exam AS Latest_exam_date, Mark
FROM new_table
WHERE Exam = 'Yes'
  AND (Student_number, Date_of_exam) IN (
    SELECT Student_number, MAX(Date_of_exam)
    FROM new_table
    WHERE Exam = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY Student_number
  )
```

- First, the query selects all rows from the new_table where Exam is 'Yes'.
- Next, it uses a subquery to find the maximum Date_of_exam for each Student_number where Exam is 'Yes'. The subquery groups the rows by Student_number, and for each group, it selects the maximum Date_of_exam.
- The outer query then filters the results from step 1 by only selecting the rows where both Exam is 'Yes' and the (Student_number, Date_of_exam) pair matches the results of the subquery from step 2.
- Finally, the query selects the Student_number, Date_of_exam, and Mark columns for the filtered rows. These columns represent the latest exam date and mark for each student where Exam is 'Yes'.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like That, Using Joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY e.Name ORDER BY e.AlarmOnTimeStamp desc) rn
    FROM @emp e
    LEFT JOIN @EMPCOMMENT ec ON ec.EmpId = e.Id
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: whats the relationship between both tables so i could set up this querry for you

Comment: SELECT * FROM ranked_messages WHERE rnt = 1  and Exam = 'Yes'

or use

SELECT Distinct * FROM ranked_messages WHERE rnt = 1  and Exam = 'Yes'

Answer (score 0):

Please try this & let me know still if you have any query

```
SELECT 
    Student_number,Exam,Mark,Date_of_exam
FROM
    tblname
WHERE
    (Student_number, Date_of_exam) IN (SELECT 
            Student_number, MAX(Date_of_exam)
        FROM
            tblname
        WHERE
            exam = 'Yes'
        GROUP BY Student_number);
```